# AWS ElasticBeanstalk instance protection for leader_only node

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celery

I have a django application running on EBS. My application runs celery beat on 1 of the instances by using the ebextension container command:

```
  03_celery_tasks:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/files/celery_configuration.txt > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && chmod 744 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
    leader_only: true
  04_celery_tasks_run:
    command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
    leader_only: true
```

During auto-scaling/or routine cleanup EBS might remove the leader_only node which cause celery scheduled task to stop running.

I know there is the ability to [protect instances during scale-in/out moments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-instance-protection.html)

However I am not sure how to enable instance protection for my leader node specifically (the one running celery beat)

**UPDATE**

I will try this solution from a certified AWS solution architect:
a https://ajbrown.org/2017/02/10/leader-election-with-aws-auto-scaling-groups.html

Comment: check this article to create your own leader election method: https://ajbrown.org/2017/02/10/leader-election-with-aws-auto-scaling-groups.html
currently that's the only solution I saw.